# NG Test show names in console

Tags: angular, angular-cli, karma-runner

It can be quite difficult to identify a failing test when there is a fairly generic error (yes source maps is false) and would help greatly if we could show the test name instead of "executed 27 of 172"

[image]

Something like "executed 27 (TextActivityService Test) of 172

I'm referring here to when all tests pass but the console is reporting errors.

Is this possible?

Comment: don't you just love the people that downvote but aren't big enough to add a comment... this is a perfectly reasonable question and if you'd been in this situation you'd understand why

Comment: I am in this situation years later. Does anyone has a solution for this? Like the logs to show the spec file that was executed. This is really a problem in case of an ERROR.

Answer (score 14):

You need to use [Karma Spec Reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-spec-reporter).

Usage:

1. To use in your own Node.js project, just execute

> npm install karma-spec-reporter --save-dev

2. Then add 'spec' to reporters in `karma.conf.js`

> // karma.conf.js
>
> ```
> ...
>   config.set({
>   ...
>     reporters: ["spec"],
>     specReporter: {
>       maxLogLines: 5,         // limit number of lines logged per test
>       suppressErrorSummary: true,  // do not print error summary
>       suppressFailed: false,  // do not print information about failed tests
>       suppressPassed: false,  // do not print information about passed tests
>       suppressSkipped: true,  // do not print information about skipped tests
>       showSpecTiming: false // print the time elapsed for each spec
>     },
>     plugins: ["karma-spec-reporter"],
>   ...
> ```

Comment: This sorta worked for me, wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but definitely a bit more info in the cli now

Comment: this solution is perfect for me. I think I will use it everywhere now.

Comment: i cannot get this to work on Angular 14, what could I missing?

Answer (score 0):

When some unit test fails, it shows `describe` and `it` message as test case name.

For example:

```
describe('TestComponent', () => {
  it('should pass test', () => {
    expect(false).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Then, the above failed unit test will be shown as `TestComponent should pass test FAILED`
`Expected false to be truthy`
in the console.

Comment: i mean when the test passes but throws an error in the console

Comment: @72GM In that case it would be better for you to add `console.log("TextActivityService Test")` at the start of the unit test. Basically, put the test name in console log.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid tbh